# Java Design: which approach is good

Tags: java, oop

What is the best practice and why??

**SingleCallBack Method:**

```
onServerResponse(boolean isSucess,Response data){
    if(isSuccess){
       // success
    }else{
      // error heandling
    }
}
```

or
**Multiple CallBack Methods:**

```
onSuccess(Response data){
}

onError(CustomException ce){
}
```

Comment: Obviously the second one.

Comment: What is the specific reason ??

Comment: Obviously the second one. For one, where is `CustomException` in the first case?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I understand that. But my question is why we will use separate methods instead of single method? I can add CustomException within single method as 3rd parameter!!

Comment: @eager and then you can also throw the SRP out of the window at the same time...

Comment: @BoristheSpider I got it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single call back has higher cyclomatic complexity compared to multiple call back. result, it is less testable. It will be apparent when you put the *real* implementation inside the methods.

From design point of view, multiple call back separates the concerns clearly.

Answer (score 4):

From the basic concept what we have learned is, the more number of methods you write , it will be more easier to maintain and more easier to understand each methods funtionality.

Comment: Any good article on that??? Is it any design pattern??

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/133404/what-is-the-ideal-length-of-a-method

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to most inputs, I feel that the first approach would have its advantages as well. Assume that you are a facebook group moderator and there are some 100 valid posts from different users that need your approval to be posted. If you notice, there is a 'Approve All' button in the fb-group-moderation-page. This allows the moderator to approve all of them in a bulk manner. If I were doing this, and fb somehow is not able to post 10 out of the 100 posts, then I would expect it to continue with the remaining 90 and post it onto the group's wall. What I am hinting at is something like a 'Partial Exception'. A problem has arose and needs to be conveyed to the client but at the same time, the criticality is not severe and processing should continue. In this case, having a single entry point like

```
onServerResponse(boolean isSucess, CustomException ex, Response data )
{
    if( ex instanceof CustomPartialException )
    {
       // Let the processing continue, but let the error population and report process be triggered as well.
    }
    else
    {
     .....
    }
}
```

So if the housekeeping tasks are segregated into different methods, we could end up with helper methods that look more or less like

```
processSuccess(Response data){
}

processError(CustomException ce){
}
```

So perhaps, the best of both worlds is what we need.

This is open to debate and would love to seek others opinion on the same.